# wrong page number in list of tables with subtables over several pages

Tags: tables, table-of-contents, floats, page-breaking, subcaption

I have a table over several pages that I've split in subtables (part 1 and part 2), so I have this  float over my pages, and in my listoftables there is only de "ending" page of my float.

This is the thing :

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[list=true]{subcaption}

\captionsetup{skip=\dimexpr\abovecaptionskip-5.5pt}
\DeclareCaptionSubType*[arabic]{table}
\captionsetup[subtable]{labelformat=simple}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{subtable}[][][c]{\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|ccc|}

\hline
Exemple & Exemple & Exemple \\
A & B & C \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Partie 1}
\end{subtable}
\end{table}

\pagebreak

\begin{table}[htbp]
\ContinuedFloat
\begin{subtable}[][][c]{\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|ccc|}
\hline
Exemple & Exemple & Exemple \\
A & B & C \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Partie 2}
\end{subtable}
\caption{Tableau 1}
\end{table}

\listoftables

\end{document}
```

The "part one" is in page2 in the list of tables and I would like to be referenced in page1... I think the problem is in the `\ContinuedFloat` but no idea what to do..

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use two captions  if you want another entry in the list of tables.

[image: a]

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[list=true]{subcaption}

\captionsetup{skip=\dimexpr\abovecaptionskip-5.5pt}
\DeclareCaptionSubType*[arabic]{table}
\captionsetup[subtable]{labelformat=simple}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{table}[htbp]
        \begin{subtable}[][][c]{\linewidth}
            \centering
            \begin{tabular}{|ccc|}              
                \hline
                Exemple & Exemple & Exemple \\
                A & B & C \\
                \hline
            \end{tabular}
            \caption{Partie 1}
        \end{subtable}
    \caption{Tableau 1 (cont.)}  % added <<<<<<<<<<
    \end{table}
    
    \newpage
    
    \begin{table}[htbp]
        \ContinuedFloat
        \begin{subtable}[][][c]{\linewidth}
            \centering
            \begin{tabular}{|ccc|}
                \hline
                Exemple & Exemple & Exemple \\
                A & B & C \\
                \hline
            \end{tabular}
            \caption{Partie 2}
        \end{subtable}
        \caption{Tableau 1}
    \end{table}
    
    \listoftables
    
\end{document
```

Comment: Humm... That was the thing ! Not quite shure how really function the caption in subtables but it was very helpfull, thank you :)